# Save cache in computer of the user PHP

Tags: php, caching

Alright?

I'm developing a system to check in online, but I need this system to work offline as well since he was born.

For example: I am connected, I loaded all contacts and I wish he armazenasse it cached on the user's device, because the internet is down I can still access this data.

How could I do this?

Hug.

Comment: php only exists on the server, so you can't do anything in php to fix the problem. You need to use a client side that php can send data too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML5 LocalStorage is your answer. Literally, in JavaScript, if the `localStorage` object is not undefined, you can use it to permanently store variables. From there, write a JSON export and use JavaScript to dump all your data into this to re-use later.

Comment: Do you have some example ou reference for me??

Comment: `localStorage.myObject = { "property": "value"};` . To recover it, just reference `localStorage.myObject["property"]`.